# Uninstalling ubuntu + partitions

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, uninstall, ext4

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed onto my dual-boot system; how can I uninstall it?

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/z3cxw.png]

Which partition(s) should I delete? As you can see, I have two used/Full up 'Other' partitions and one ext4 partition. The two other partitions have the partition id: (0x82) and the ext4 partition has: (0x83).

How can I safely uninstall Ubuntu, without screwing up the bootloader) (I found a program somewhere which can fix the Windows bootloader but forgot the name)